# Test to compare large and small datasets

Tags: categorical-data, contingency-tables

I send Alice and Bob out to record people's eye colour (blue, brown, green, other). Alice does a great job and writes down the eye colour of 2000 people. Bob only records the eye colour of 20 people. Alice found all 2000 people had brown eyes. Bob found 19 people with brown eyes and one with green eyes. How important is the one green result? How can I compare the results? Is the green result significant?

**Update**
I now send Alice and Bob out to a different area on another day. Alice is thorough and finds 2000 people again, while Bob is still lazy and only finds 20 people. Their results would look something like this:

```
| Day | Dataset | Blue | Brown | Green | Other |
|  1  | Alice   | 0    | 2000  | 0     | 0     |
|  1  | Bob     | 0    | 19    | 1     | 0     |
|  2  | Alice   | 10   | 1900  | 45    | 45    |
|  2  | Bob     | 2    | 10    | 6     | 6     |
```

I repeat this process, sending them out to different areas on different days. Alice always finds 2000 people and Bob always finds 20.

Considering each day separately, how can I determine if Alice or Bob's results are more representative of the population they sampled on a given day? How can I compare their results for a given day?

Comment: You have tagged this "hypothesis-testing" but you have not stated any hypothesis or hypotheses to test. Without a hypothesis, significance cannot be assessed.

Comment: Update: You removed the tag, but you are still asking about significance. One possible hypothesis is that Alice and Bob's data are compatible, which requires examination of the two-way table (2000, 0; 19, 1). I'd  recommend Fisher's exact test for such a table. As neither A nor B found blue or other colours, it is hard to see that you can put those zero frequencies into a test.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: How representative samples are of the population cannot be assessed just from the samples. Comparing Alice and Bob for a given day is a two-way contingency table: see almost any introductory text with good coverage of categorical data, looking for chi-square test and Fisher exact test.